# Delete points between hours in InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb

I have a measurement that stores prices for every 10 seconds (their seconds last with 0-10-20-30-40-50).
I would like to delete old points (older than 1 year) to keep only prices every hour.

How to get these candidates?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with Retention Policy + Continuous Query:

```
CREATE RETENTION POLICY "one_year" ON "database_name" DURATION 52w REPLICATION 1 DEFAULT
```

`autogen` RP has an infinite retention duration:

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY "aggregate_prices" ON "database_name"
BEGIN
    SELECT mean("value") 
    INTO "autogen"."prices" 
    FROM "prices" 
    GROUP BY time(1h)
END
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but is there any way to delete these prices from autogen to save disk usage?

Comment: Pardon me if I misunderstood the question, but you asked "to delete points older than 1 year" and "keep only prices every hour". My understanding was that you wanted to keep prices data with discrete step of 1 hour instead of 10 seconds. In case, if you don't need to keep anything older then 1 year at all, you don't need a continuous query - pure 1 year retention policy will do the job. Continuous queries just help you to aggregate the data by longer time intervals, which in turn will save you quite some disk space while still keeping the generalized data.